# telerik radgrid selecting item after inserting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

Im programatically changing dataSource of the grid by inserting item to the list. Then I do Rebind on the RadGrid. Ive got an id of newly inserted object. Then I would like select this row in grid. How can I do this from code behind  ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the ID as a `DataKeyNames="yourID"` for your grid. Then you can retrieve it in the code behind and set it selected like this:

```
GridDataItem gdiItem = RarGrid1.MasterTableView.FindItemByKeyValue("yourID", yourIDValue);
gdiItem.Selected = true;
```

Comment: First problem is with pagination. I had to dissable it to find given key (cause it was on the different page). Second problem is that gridItem.Selected = true doesnt invoke OnSelectedIndexChanged event on my grid :(

Comment: @gruber Yes I know of this problems. Your question asked only to select the item. If you want to fire the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event then you should have posted some code of the event hadler to see what you want to do with the item. And the pagination is not a problem if you know the page size, you can then jump to the page that contains your item.

Comment: How can I change currentPageIndex ? (Im talking about jumping to the page which contains item im interested in)

Comment: @gruber If you know the page size, you can .Skip().Take() records from the collection until you find the record you need and then set the `currentPageIndex` to that page. If you need coda, please ask a question because comments are not friendly to write code...

Comment: here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646219/finding-records-in-radgrid-telerik-with-pagination