# Finding records in RadGrid Telerik with pagination

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How is it possible to find given record by key in the radGrid when pagination is enabled ? After insert of an element I would like to select new row that why I need this functionality.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

One way is to disable paging, then make a `Rebind`, then iterate through all the items, find the page the item should be in and then enable paging. The other way is to make separate `Rebind` per page, like this:

```
int count = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.PageCount;  
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{ 
    RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = i; 
    RadGrid1.Rebind();

    foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in RadGrid1.Items) 
    { 
        var yourID = dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("YourID"); 
        if (yourID == insertedItemID)
           break;
    }  
}     
RadGrid1.Rebind();
```

For more info and an example, check the Telerik forums. This links are useful:

- [RadGrid - select row on other page](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-select-row-on-other-page.aspx)
- [How to count selected items in RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-to-count-selected-items-in-radgrid.aspx)
- [Getting total number of rows in a grid](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/getting-total-number-of-rows-in-a-grid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link from Telerik that will select the Last Updated, or Last Inserted row.

[Select last Updated or Inserted row in Telerik RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/select-inserted-updated-row-after-performing-command.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
RadGrid1.AllowPaging = false;
RadGrid1.Rebind();

foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in RadGrid1.Items) 
{ 
    var yourID = dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("YourID"); 
    if (yourID == insertedItemID)
       break;
}
```

RadGrid1.AllowPaging = true;
RadGrid1.Rebind();